# Let $a,b,c> 0$, $abc = 1$. Prove that $\frac{a}{(a+3)^2} + \frac{b}{(b+3)^2} + \frac{c}{(c+3)^2} ≤ \frac{3}{16}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a$,$b$,$c$ be positive reals such that $abc = 1$ . Prove that $\frac{a}{(a+3)^2} + \frac{b}{(b+3)^2} + \frac{c}{(c+3)^2} ≤ \frac{3}{16}$

**What I've tried :**

Well I was trying directly multiplying both sides by $(a+3)^2(b+3)^2(c+3)^2$ but it's too lengthy and seemed complex so any better way to solve it ?

Comment: You could try the standard substitution $a=x/y,b=y/z,c=z/x$ to remove the condition $abc=1$ and get an equivalent inequality for all positive reals.

Comment: @SB1729 but sir won't it be more complex to prove ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This partial solution is too long to be a comment, and I think, it solves a large case of the problem. I hope someone can get it finished.

---

**Lemma:** If $x\leq y\leq z$, then we have:
$$\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{y+z}+\frac{z}{z+x}\leq \frac{3}{2}.$$

**Proof:** WLOG, we assume $x=1$, hence $1\leq y \leq z$;

$$\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{y}{y+z}+\frac{z}{z+1}\leq \frac{3}{2} \iff z^2(y-1)+z(1-y^2)+(y^2-y) \geq  0 \\ \iff (y-1)(z-y)(z-1)\geq 0,$$

which is obvious.

---

Now, let's assume $a=\frac{x}{y}, b=\frac{y}{z}, c=\frac{z}{x}$ such that $c \geq 1 \geq b \geq a$, which implies $x\leq y \leq z.$

We get:

$$\frac{a}{(a+3)^2}+\frac{b}{(b+3)^2}+\frac{c}{(c+3)^2}= \\ \frac{xy}{(x+3y)^2}+\frac{yz}{(y+3z)^2}+\frac{zx}{(z+3x)^2}= \\ \frac{xy}{x^2+6xy+9y^2}+\frac{yz}{y^2+6yz+9z^2}+\frac{zx}{z^2+6zx+9x^2} \leq \\ \frac{xy}{8xy+8y^2}+\frac{yz}{8yz+8z^2}+\frac{zx}{8zx+8x^2}=\frac{1}{8}(\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{y+z}+\frac{z}{z+x}) \leq \frac{3}{16}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately $\sum \frac{x}{x+y} \leqslant \frac32$ doesn't hold for $x\leqslant z\leqslant y$, so this solution is incomplete (and cannot be completed, as the supremum is $2$).

Comment: @Macavity Yes. You are right. This solution is incomplete as I wrote in the post. I think a very different approach should be used.

Comment: As the function $f(a)=\frac{a}{(a+3)^2}$ has $f''$ changing signs, methods which essentially rely on convexity like CS, AM-GM, tangent line method etc. wont be directly useful.  Homogenisation and full expansion may allow a solution using BW - not elegant or practical though unless using a CAS.

Comment: @Ash_Blanc Hi! Please note this solution of mine is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using pqr method:

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc = 1$. Using $p^3 \ge 27r$, we have $p \ge 3$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$27\,{q}^{2}+ \left( 18\,p-1240 \right) q+243\,{p}^{2}+24\,p+1056 \ge 0. \tag{1}$$
(Details are given at the end.)

(1) is written as
$$\frac{1}{27}(620 - 27q - 9p)^2 + \frac{16}{27}(45p + 377)(9p - 59) \ge 0.$$

We only need to prove the case that
$9p - 59 < 0$.

By Schur inequality $a(a-b)(a-c) + b(b-c)(b-a)+c(c-a)(c-b)\ge 0$
which is written as $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$, we have
$$q \le \frac{p^3 + 9}{4p}.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 620 - 27q - 9p
 &\ge 620 - 27\cdot \frac{p^3 + 9}{4p} - 9p\\
 &= 620 - \frac{27}{4}p^2 - \frac{243}{4p} - 9p\\
 &\ge 620 - \frac{27}{4}\cdot 8^2 - \frac{243}{4\cdot 3} - 9\cdot 8\\
 &> 0
\end{align*}
where we use $3 \le p < 59/9 < 8$.

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{27}\left(620 - 27\cdot \frac{p^3 + 9}{4p} - 9p\right)^2 + \frac{16}{27}(45p + 377)(9p - 59) \ge 0.$$
or
$${\frac { \left( p-3 \right)  \left( 27\,{p}^{5}+153\,{p}^{4}-613
  \,{p}^{3}-969\,{p}^{2}+14637\,p-729 \right) }{16{p}^{2}}} \ge 0
$$
which is true (using $p \ge 3$).

We are done.

---

About the pqr expression (1):

Using $\frac{a}{(a+3)^2} = \frac{1}{a+ 3} - \frac{3}{(a+3)^2}$, the desired inequality is written as
$$\frac{3}{16} + \frac{3}{(a+3)^2} + \frac{3}{(b+3)^2} + \frac{3}{(c+3)^2} - \frac{1}{a+ 3} - \frac{1}{b+ 3} - \frac{1}{c+ 3} \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{3}{16} + 3\left(\frac{1}{a+ 3} + \frac{1}{b+ 3} + \frac{1}{c+ 3}\right)^2 - \frac{6(a + 3 + b + 3 + c + 3)}{(a + 3)(b + 3)(c+3)}- \frac{1}{a+ 3} - \frac{1}{b+ 3} - \frac{1}{c+ 3} \ge 0.$$

We have
$$(a + 3)(b + 3)(c + 3)
= abc + 3(ab + bc + ca) + 9(a + b + c) + 27 = 1 + 3q + 9p + 27$$
and
$$\frac{1}{a+ 3} + \frac{1}{b+ 3} + \frac{1}{c+ 3}
= \frac{ab + bc + ca + 6(a + b + c) + 27}{(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)}
= \frac{q + 6p + 27}{1 + 3q + 9p + 27}.$$

Thus, the desired pqr expression is
$$\frac{3}{16} + 3\left(\frac{q + 6p + 27}{1 + 3q + 9p + 27}\right)^2
- \frac{6(p + 9)}{1 + 3q + 9p + 27}
- \frac{q + 6p + 27}{1 + 3q + 9p + 27} \ge 0$$
which is simplified to (1).

Comment: Hi. Honestly speaking, it is very hard for me to follow the computations if not saying impossible. Did you use computers?

Comment: @RezaRajaei The computation burden is the pqr expression of the original inequality. It took some time to do it by hand. I admit it is not nice (by hand). As you may have noticed, there is no proof here, so I posted it.

Comment: I see. I hope the OP unaccepts my post and accepts yours so that the future readers won't be confused.

Comment: @RezaRajaei Not necessary. Your answer as partial proof is nice. It is possible you will complete the rest in the future. My proof is still not nice due to full expanding. Hope to see a proof without full expanding.

Answer (score 1):

***Not a solution, just some thoughts. Perhaps someone can follow through.***

if we apply the substitution $u=a+3, v=b+3,w=c+3$

the original inequality becomes$$\frac{u-3}{u^2}+\frac{v-3}{v^2}+\frac{w-3}{w^2}=\\\frac{1}{u}-\frac{3}{u^2}+\frac{1}{v}-\frac{3}{v^2}+\frac{1}{w}-\frac{3}{w^2}=\\\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{w}-3\Big(\frac{1}{u^2}+\frac{1}{v^2}+\frac{1}{w^2}\Big)\le\frac3{16}$$

Now, if $$f(x)=\frac1{x}-\frac3{x^2}-\frac1{16}$$

for $x\in (0, +\infty)$, it is enough to show that $f(u)+f(v)+f(w)\le0,$ $\forall u,v,w \in (0, +\infty)$ under the condition $u,v,w\gt3$ and$(u-3)(v-3)(w-3)=1$.

Comment: Upto substitution not a bad idea